# How to handle changes made from other devices logged in on the same account?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Let's say that the user is logged in on two phones.

On `phone1`, he goes to his profile page and changes `setting1` but doesn't press 'Save', yet.

Meanhwile, the same user, on `phone2`, changes another setting, `setting2` and saves.

During the call made to the database made on `phone2`, he presses the `Save` button on `phone1`.

Since `phone1` doesn't know about the new changes made from `phone2`, if `setting1` is dependent on `setting2`, it will mess things up.

How should one handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch user record with help of `FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged`.
Whenever the change occur on firebase databases your block/closure for observer will be called and you can change that particular values.

For e.g.:

```
// Listen for change comments in the Firebase database
yourRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  <update your values>
})
```